# Recommended books for wpf custom control design-time features

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, custom-controls, design-time, cider

I have some custom controls that I would like to make more 'user friendly' in Cider (VS wpf designer). I have red all the documentation in MSDN and some sites that I found through google , but I did not find answers to some simple questions :

1. How to set default values for the items that are created from a collection editor (like columns in datagrid, not drag-drop from toolbox)
2. How to generate XAML (like the datagrid dose when you click generate columns)

Please let me know if you know of any doc that goes into details such as those mentioned above.

Also if you know/have any custom controls with visible source code that have designer support (like Xceed or DevExpress) please share a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an excellent and rare book that goes deep into custom controls development:

[WPF Control Development Unleashed: Building Advanced User Experiences](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672330334)

Comment: Thanks you are right, this is a good book (I read it) however it contains very few details about how to interact with the VS designer (Citrix))

Answer (score 2):

Recommended books:

1- [www.amazon.com/Pro-WPF-2012-Presentation-Professionals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430243651)
2- any book about Design Pattern like [www.amazon.com/3-0-Design-Patterns-Judith-Bishop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059652773X)
3- [MVVM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735650926) 
to add a column to data grid you don't need to generate xaml, there is a column collection you can add one by code behind

```
dataGrid1.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn{ Header = "column1"});
```

read the first book well and you will be good

Comment: I think maybe I was not clear in what I want to do. I want to develop a custom control with Visual Studio designer support. I have seen that there is a button (more like a link actually) in the default WPF datagrid control : Generate Columns. I would like my custom control to have a similar functionality. That means I should be able to generate XAML when the user dose something in the designer. I have seen that if I add columns in the control's constructor Xaml is generated but at that time I do not have the info required to generate the columns (DataContext). Other places seem to not generate